# Migrating database to a new server

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, migration, key

We recently got a new server, so we tried moving our database over (made a backup of it). I have an encrypted column in one of the tables, however, and when we tried this migration technique the master key was deleted. Is there a way to copy over the database to the new server without losing all the information for my encrypted column? (master key, certificate, symmetric key, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The master key was not deleted - it is not moved when you move the encrypted database.  You need to back it up from your old server and then restore it to the new server.  Here are some links to help you backup and restore the master key:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174387.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186336.aspx